# Removing the timestamps from date in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, datetime

My company gave me a job to automate the excel tasks using python to save time. Now I have loaded the excel to jupyter notebook using the code. Now all the dates in my excel sheet after loading changed to date with timestamps.

```
import pandas as pd
file_path = pd.ExcelFile(r'C:\Users\User\Downloads\Report4.xlsx')

workbook = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=None, dtype=str)
```

I have used dtype = 'str' because some column values start with 0 but they dont get printed if I load it as it is.

Now I removed the timestamps from column headers. But I couldnt remove it from cell values. I tried everything online but nothing worked. I saw the stackoverflow posts but that also didnt work for me.

I want to change the date format from
2021-05-10 00:00:00 to mm/dd/yyyy.

It would be great if someone could help me resolve this. Thank you.

Comment: Just to begin, are you able to separate the string "2021-05-10 00:00:00" in "2021-05-10" and "00:00:00" ?

Comment: No. Plus I forgot to mention I have 7-8 date columns

Comment: in the Excel sheet, how is the date column *formatted*? is it a date/time (Excel serial date) or a string (Text)?

Comment: In Excel it is in mm/dd/yyyy format. No time.

Comment: I mean the column type, not how it's displayed. If you load excel data to a pandas dataframe and a date/time column is of dtype datetime in the dataframe, this normally means it was an excel serial date type column in the spreadsheet. If you want a string dtype column with dates represented as mm/dd/yyyy, you could format to string using `.dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")`, see [dt accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you have string date-time values and want to deal with strings throughout or use datetime objects. Its not difficult either way. But assuming all strings then you can simply use split() to extract the elements then recombine.

```
d = "2021-05-10 00:00:00"

my_date = d.split()[0]
dl = my_date.split('-')
my_date_final = f"{dl[1]}/{dl[2]}/{dl[0]}"

print(my_date_final)
```

gives

```
05/10/2021
```

Assuming all values have the same format then you could wrap the code in function and use df.applymap to convert the required columns:

```
def func(x):
    dl = x.split()[0].split('-')
    return f"{dl[1]}/{dl[2]}/{dl[0]}"

df2 = df[['col1', 'col2']].applymap(func)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dataframe DF with a column called "date_time" containing data with this format "2021-05-10 00:00:00" you first need to separate date from time:

```
import pandas as pd

DF[['date', 'time']] = DF["date_time"].str.split(" ", expand = True)
```

this will add two new columns calle d "date" and "time to your dataframe

Now define your date format

```
DF = pd.to_datetime(DF["date"], format='%mm.%dd.%yyyy')
```

Comment: I have 8 columns. I cant split them and then delete time column them